# Hadoop Streaming 1.0.3 Unrecognized -D command

Tags: hadoop, streaming

I am trying to chain some Streaming jobs( jobs written in Python). I did it, but I have problem with -D commands. Here is the code,

```
public class OJs extends Configured implements Tool
{
public int run( String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //DOMINATION
    Path domin      = new Path( "diploma/join.txt");
    //dominationm.py
    Path domout     = new Path( "mapkeyout/");
    //dominationr.py

    String[] dom = new String[]
    {
        "-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0",
        "-file"     , "/home/hduser/optimizingJoins/dominationm.py" ,
        "-mapper"   , "dominationm.py"                              ,
        "-file"     , "/home/hduser/optimizingJoins/dominationr.py" ,
        "-reducer"  , "dominationr.py",         
        "-input"    , domin.toString()                              ,
        "-output"   , domout.toString()
    };
    JobConf domConf = new StreamJob().createJob( dom);
    //run domination job
    JobClient.runJob( domConf);
    return 0;
}//end run

public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int res = ToolRunner.run( new Configuration(), new OJs(), args);
    System.exit( res);
}//end main
}//end OJs
```

My problem is with command "-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0". I get this error,

```
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Unrecognized option: -D...
```

where the ... include any possible syntax combination, i.e.

```
"-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0"
"-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0"
"-D", "mapred.reduce.tasks=0"
"-D", "mapred.reduce.tasks=", "0"
" -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0"
```

etc.

When I have a space before -D, then this command is ignored. I don't have the number of reducers I  specified. When I don't have this space, I get the error I mentioned.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Substituting -D option with -jobconf doesn't solve the problem. Here is the whole error output,

```
 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

    12/10/04 00:25:02 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Unrecognized option: -jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0
    Usage: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar \
          $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar [options]

    Options:
   -input    <path>     DFS input file(s) for the Map step

   -output   <path>     DFS output directory for the Reduce step

   -mapper   <cmd|JavaClassName>      The streaming command to run

   -combiner <cmd|JavaClassName> The streaming command to run

   -reducer  <cmd|JavaClassName>      The streaming command to run

   -file     <file>     File/dir to be shipped in the Job jar file

   -inputformat TextInputFormat(default)|SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat|JavaClassName Optional.

   -outputformat TextOutputFormat(default)|JavaClassName  Optional.

   -partitioner JavaClassName  Optional.

   -numReduceTasks <num>  Optional.

   -inputreader <spec>  Optional.

   -cmdenv   <n>=<v>    Optional. Pass env.var to streaming commands

   -mapdebug <path>  Optional. To run this script when a map task fails 

   -reducedebug <path>  Optional. To run this script when a reduce task fails 

   -io <identifier>  Optional.

   -verbose

   Generic options supported are

   -conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file

   -D <property=value>            use value for given property

   -fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode

   -jt <local|jobtracker:port>    specify a job tracker

   -files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster

   -libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.

   -archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

   The general command line syntax is
   bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]


   For more details about these options:

   Use $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar build/hadoop-streaming.jar -info

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.fail(StreamJob.java:549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.exitUsage(StreamJob.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.parseArgv(StreamJob.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.createJob(StreamJob.java:143)
    at OJs.run(OJs.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at OJs.main(OJs.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Moreover, I can't understand, why when I run a job straight with Streaming, Streaming recognizes -D option, but when I run a job with Streaming through JobClient, -D option recognition fails. Is a problem of Streaming or a problem of sun.reflect? Where is sun.reflect package in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the line

```
..."-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0"...
```

should be written as

```
..."-D", "mapred.reduce.tasks=0"...
```

This is the standard pattern of commands,

```
"-commandname", "value"
```

To continue, a program generally may accepts or not some arguments. These arguments in Hadoop context are called options. There are two kinds of them, generic and streaming, job specific. The [generic options](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options) are handled from [GenericOptionsParser](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html). [Job specific options](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/streaming.html#Streaming+Command+Options) in the context of Hadoop Streaming are handled from StreamJob.

So, the way -D option is set in the code of the initial question, is wrong. This is because -D is a generic option. StreamJob can't handle generic options. StreamJob can handle -jobconf however, which is a job specific option. So the line

```
..."-D", "mapred.reduce.tasks=0"...
```

is writtern correctly as

```
..."-jobconf", "mapred.reduce.tasks=0"...
```

With -jobconf  this warning is raised,

```
WARN streaming.StreamJob: -jobconf option is deprecated, please use -D instead.
```

To avoid this warning -D option is needed and consequently a GenericOptionsParser is needed to parse -D option.

To move on, when someone runs a streaming job using the command

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar [ generic options] [ streaming( job specific) options]
```

what really happens? Why in this case there is no problem? In this case, both generic and job specific options are parsed properly. This is possible because of the Tool interface that takes care of the generic options through GenericOptionsParser. The job specific options are handled from the StreamJob() inside hadoop-streaming-*.jar.

Indeed hadoop-streaming-*.jar has a file "HadoopStreaming.java" responsible for jobs submitted the way above. The HadoopStreaming class calls ToolRunner.run() with two arguments. The first argument is a new StreamJob object and the second consists of all the command line options i.e. [ generic options] and [ streaming( job specific) options]. The GenericOptionsParser separates generic from job specific options by parsing only the generic ones. Then, the GenericOptionsParser returns the rest of the options i.e. job specific which are parsed from the StreamJob(). StreamJob is invoked through Tool.run( [ job specific args]) where Tool = StreamJob. See [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) and [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) to have an intuition why Tool = StreamJob.

In conclusion,

GenericOptionsParser -> generic options,

StreamJob            -> streaming( job specific) options.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like StreamJob doesn't support the `-Dkey=value` generic configuration options.

See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming, but looks like you need to use (and is explicitly called out as an example on that page):

```
-jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0
```

Comment: You solved the problem in the end. I was using jobconf mistakenly. Despite that, I figured out a lot of other interesting and important things. I talk about them in my answer. Thanks!